# Using URL Routing for Web Forms and StopRoutingHandler for Favicon

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have a website where I need to add a Favicon.ico.  The site is written using ASP.NET 3.5 Web Forms with Routing.  The issue is that the Favicon link always returns a page not found error.  This is because the Routing does not know where the link for Favicon.ico should go to so it returns the Not Found page.

I have tried to add a StopRoutingHandler for the the favicon but none of them seem to work.  Below are the ones I have tried so far:

```
routes.Add(new Route("MasterPages/{favicon}.ico", new StopRoutingHandler()));
routes.Add(new Route("{favicon}.ico", new StopRoutingHandler()));
routes.Add(new Route("favicon.ico", new StopRoutingHandler()));
routes.Add(new Route("favicon.ico/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Does anyone know what I should be using?  My favicon.ico links I have tried look like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And they are inside of my `<html><head>` tags.

Also, as one final note, I am not using MVC because if I was I could use this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});
```

Unfortunately, IgnoreRoute does not work for Routing Web Forms though because it is not an MVC application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this and it worked:

```
routes.Add(new Route("favicon.ico", new StaticFileRouteHandler("~/favicon.ico")));

public class StaticFileRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public string VirtualPath { get; set; }
    public StaticFileRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public System.Web.IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(VirtualPath);
        return new DefaultHttpHandler();
    }
}
```

Apparently this works too:

```
routes.Add(new Route("favicon.ico", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

I just needed to close Firefox, clear my history and try again.

Comment: This also helps;
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />