# Providing access to physical folder in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 applciation's root project folder I have a special folder `Themes`, that uses 3-rd party themes, it is a list of scripts, css, images, font `*.woff` files, that use their own sub-folder structure, I want to expose this folder contents, under some specific part of my URL for example `http://MySite.com/Themes/...`, I don't want to use bundling and minification for this purpose, because it would require me to invest huge effort into recompiling all of the existing scripts, investigate their contents, etc. Is there a way to just to open read access to that folder?

Comment: Just give the user IIS is running the site under read access to that directory.

Comment: Since it lives inside the web project, it should just work with no special handling (`http://MySite.com/Themes/somescript.js` should come up just fine in the browser). What problem are you having?

Comment: Can you do something with the [StopRoutingHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500750/using-url-routing-for-web-forms-and-stoproutinghandler-for-favico)?

Comment: You want to use the Ignore route. There should already be one for css.

Comment: It seems that the web server is not letting the *.woff files to go out
`The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration`

Comment: this post helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts